# How do I add a website to a virtual network in Windows Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role, azure-virtual-network

Scenario:

I have a website on Windows Azure. That website needs to connect to a (new) Azure VM.

I have done the following:

- Created new Virtual Network on Azure
- Added the VM to the Virtual Network, and it does get an IP in the virtual network.
- I have configured the appropiate Endpoint for the VM (Public/Private port).

Now, how do I "connect" the Azure website to the same virtual network, such that my .NET code in the website can create a TCP connection to the VM on it's IP on the Virtual Network ?

Comment: I think you'd have to create a VM on the virtual network and deploy the website to that VM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is now possible. Be sure to use the NEW Azure Portal. For details, check out:
http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/09/15/azure-websites-virtual-network-integration/

Answer (score 1):

Currently you cannot connect/add Azure Web Site to a Virtual Network. You can only add VMs and Cloud Services to a Virtual Network. However this is a demanded feature and I believe we will see it in the future releases of the Web Sites service (my speculation).

Comment: I hope this is added soon. Seems like a huge security hole for redis if hosted in VM on linux. If not would be nice to know how to secure redis properly in a linux vm where a Azure Website is connecting to it.

Comment: the only possible way today is to use Azure Cloud Service (Web Role/worker Role) to securely connect to an Azure VM via Azure VNet.

Comment: I also have a postgres db running in Linux that would need to be secured. So that would only work for redis. Seems like a huge security hole. We also have more complexity in that our Azure Websites auto scale meaning adding or removing (scale down) of ip's. How does that change firewall rules automatically?

Comment: you will not have this issue if you use Web Roles and VNet! Or wait until (if ever) Web Sites come to suppot VNet. So there is a **secure** solution **today**, which means there is no security hole.

Answer (score -3):

The key  here is to create the Virtual Network before the Virtual Machine and then place the VM in the VN during it's creation. The article here gives instructions moving a VM into a VN.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walterm/archive/2013/05/29/moving-a-virtual-machine-from-one-virtual-network-to-another.aspx